# How to get PID of all running Java applications programmatically?

Tags: java

I need to find the PID of all running java applications using my program.

Comment: Hey, looks like your real question should be "how to kill a process using jps". You should modify your question to make it clear. Also please note that, both Netbeans and VisualVM have the name Main in the jps results, even with `jps -ml` there may be problem because the command line parameters are not reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"ps", "-ef", "|", "grep", "java"});

final char[] buffer = new char[0x10000];
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
int read;
do {
    read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (read>0) {
        out.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} while (read>=0);
process.destroy();

System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

Run [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) process from your application.

Comment: Hi, where can I run jps? from the command prompt? it does not recognize it there.

Comment: OK thank you got that working. Now can you tell me how I can kill a particular process programmatically using jps?

Comment: One way could be: read output of `jps -ml`, search for specified name from the output and parse the corresponding pid, and run `kill -9 PID`.